# How to sum the output inside the while loop

Tags: c++

I have a code that contains random integers 'boxes'. I need to sum those integers inside the while loop.

I tried to use 'for loop' inside while loop but it didn't work.

```
    int i = 1;
    while (i <= chambers ){

        //chambers = chambers + 1;

        boxes = (rand() % 100) + 1;
        cout << "In chamber number " << i << " you found "
        << boxes << " boxes of gold!" << endl;

        i++;

    }
```

Example output:

```
I need to sum the 'boxes': Output Example: 
In chamber number 1 you found 8 boxes of gold!
In chamber number 2 you found 50 boxes of gold!
In chamber number 3 you found 74 boxes of gold!
In chamber number 4 you found 59 boxes of gold!
In chamber number 5 you found 31 boxes of gold!
In chamber number 6 you found 73 boxes of gold!

There are 295 boxes of gold in this cave
```

Comment: You mean like a counter variable outside the loop to count all the stuff inside the loop?

Comment: it's not possible to count inside is it?

Comment: Using a for loop inside the while loop is the wrong strategy, and shows you are not yet thinking clearly about how to translate what you want into real code. What you should do is add another variable to your code for the total of the boxes. Each time round the while loop add the numnber of boxes to the total number of boxes variable and when the while loop ends your new variable will have total of all the boxes.

Comment: @Chyngyz Yes it is possible to count inside, that's exactly how you should do it.

Comment: I am confused even more now...

Comment: ok I see what u mean that was a stupid question. My bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this, add a new variable to hold a running total of the number of boxes. At the end of the while loop the running total will be the total of all the boxes.

```
int total_boxes = 0;
int i = 1;
while (i <= chambers ){

    //chambers = chambers + 1;

    boxes = (rand() % 100) + 1;
    cout << "In chamber number " << i << " you found "
        << boxes << " boxes of gold!" << endl;
    total_boxes += boxes; // total boxes so far
    i++;

}
cout << "There are " << total_boxes << " boxes of gold\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a global variable out side while loop and do like this
sum  = 0 and then inside loop sum=sum+output.and print the value out side the loop.

Comment: Don't make global variables, global variables are bad (as a general rule). Make a variable where you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Use an auxiliary variable like `boxes_total`.  Initialize it before entering the while to `boxes_total=0` and add at the end of your while `boxes_total = boxes_total + boxes`.